# How do you compute the distance between text documents for k-means with word2vec?

Tags: nlp, k-means, word2vec

I have recently been introduced to word2vec and I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how exactly it is used for k-means clustering.

I do understand how k-means works with tf-idf vectors. For each text document you have a vector of tf-idf values and after choosing some documents as initial cluster centers, you can use the euclidian distance to minimise the the distances between the vectors of the documents. Here's an [example](https://www.experfy.com/blog/k-means-clustering-in-text-data).

However, when using word2vec, each word is represented as a vector. Does this mean that each document corresponds to a matrix? And if so, how do you compute the minimum distance w.r.t. other text documents?

**Question:** How do you compute the distance between text documents for k-means with word2vec?

**Edit:** To explain my confusion in a bit more detail, please consider the following code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences_tfidf)
print(tfidf_matrix.toarray())

model = Word2Vec(sentences_word2vec, min_count=1)

word2vec_matrix = model[model.wv.vocab]
print(len(word2vec_matrix))
for i in range(0,len(word2vec_matrix)):
    print(X[i])
```

It returns the following code:

```
[[ 0.          0.55459491  0.          0.          0.35399075  0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.437249
   0.35399075  0.35399075  0.35399075  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.44302215  0.2827753   0.          0.
   0.          0.34928375  0.          0.          0.          0.34928375
   0.          0.2827753   0.5655506   0.2827753   0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.35101741  0.          0.          0.27674616
   0.35101741  0.          0.          0.35101741  0.          0.35101741
   0.27674616  0.27674616  0.44809973  0.          0.          0.27674616]
 [ 0.40531999  0.          0.          0.          0.2587105   0.31955894
   0.          0.40531999  0.31955894  0.          0.40531999  0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.2587105   0.2587105   0.31955894]]
20
[  4.08335682e-03  -4.44161100e-03   3.92342824e-03   3.96498619e-03
   6.99949533e-06  -2.14108804e-04   1.20419310e-03  -1.29191438e-03
   1.64671184e-03   3.41688609e-03  -4.94929403e-03   2.90348311e-03
   4.23802016e-03  -3.01274913e-03  -7.36164337e-04   3.47558968e-03
  -7.02908786e-04   4.73567843e-03  -1.42914290e-03   3.17237526e-03
   9.36070050e-04  -2.23833631e-04  -4.03443904e-04   4.97530040e-04
  -4.82502300e-03   2.42140982e-03  -3.61089432e-03   3.37070058e-04
  -2.09900597e-03  -1.82093668e-03  -4.74618562e-03   2.41499138e-03
  -2.15628324e-03   3.43719614e-03   7.50159554e-04  -2.05973233e-03
   1.92534993e-03   1.96503079e-03  -2.02400610e-03   3.99564439e-03
   4.95056808e-03   1.47033704e-03  -2.80071306e-03   3.59585625e-04
  -2.77896033e-04  -3.21732066e-03   4.36303904e-03  -2.16396619e-03
   2.24438333e-03  -4.50925855e-03  -4.70488053e-03   6.30825118e-04
   3.81869613e-03   3.75767215e-03   5.01064525e-04   1.70175335e-03
  -1.26033701e-04  -7.43318116e-04  -6.74833194e-04  -4.76678275e-03
   1.53754558e-03   2.32421421e-03  -3.23472451e-03  -8.32759659e-04
   4.67014220e-03   5.15853462e-04  -1.15449808e-03  -1.63017167e-03
  -2.73897988e-03  -3.95627553e-03   4.04657237e-03  -1.79282576e-03
  -3.26930732e-03   2.85121426e-03  -2.33304151e-03  -2.01760884e-03
  -3.33597139e-03  -1.19233003e-03  -2.12347694e-03   4.36858647e-03
   2.00414215e-03  -4.23572073e-03   4.98410035e-03   1.79121632e-03
   4.81655030e-03   3.33247939e-03  -3.95260006e-03   1.19335402e-03
   4.61675343e-04   6.09758368e-04  -4.74696746e-03   4.91552567e-03
   1.74517138e-03   2.36604619e-03  -3.06009664e-04   3.62954312e-03
   3.56943789e-03   2.92139384e-03  -4.27138479e-03  -3.51175456e-03]
[ -4.14272398e-03   3.45513038e-03  -1.47538856e-04  -2.02292087e-03
  -2.96578306e-04   1.88684417e-03  -2.63865804e-03   2.69249966e-03
   4.57606697e-03   2.19206396e-03   2.01336667e-03   1.47434452e-03
   1.88332598e-03  -1.14452699e-03  -1.35678309e-03  -2.02636060e-04
  -3.26160830e-03  -3.95368552e-03   1.40415027e-03   2.30542314e-03
  -3.18884710e-03  -4.46776347e-03   3.96415358e-03  -2.07852037e-03
   4.98413946e-03  -6.43568579e-04  -2.53325375e-03   1.30117545e-03
   1.26555841e-03  -8.84680718e-04  -8.34991166e-04  -4.15050285e-03
   4.66807076e-04   1.71844949e-04   1.08140183e-03   4.37910948e-03
  -3.28412466e-03   2.09890743e-04   2.29888223e-03   4.70223464e-03
  -2.31004297e-03  -5.10134443e-04   2.57104915e-03  -2.55978899e-03
  -7.55646848e-04  -1.98197929e-04   1.20443532e-04   4.63618943e-03
   1.13036349e-05   8.16594984e-04  -1.65917678e-03   3.29331891e-03
  -4.97825304e-03  -2.03667139e-03   3.60272871e-03   7.44500838e-04
  -4.40325850e-04   6.38399797e-04  -4.23364760e-03  -4.56386572e-03
   4.77551389e-03   4.74880403e-03   7.06148741e-04  -1.24937459e-03
  -9.50689311e-04  -3.88551364e-03  -4.45985980e-03  -1.15060725e-03
   3.27067473e-03   4.54987818e-03   2.62327422e-03  -2.40981602e-03
   4.55576897e-04   3.19155119e-03  -3.84227419e-03  -1.17610034e-03
  -1.45622855e-03  -4.32460709e-03  -4.12792247e-03  -1.74557802e-03
   4.66075348e-04   3.39668151e-03  -4.00651991e-03   1.41077011e-03
  -7.89384532e-04  -6.56061340e-04   1.14822399e-03   4.12205653e-03
   3.60721885e-03  -3.11746349e-04   1.44255662e-03   3.11965472e-03
  -4.93455213e-03   4.80490318e-03   2.79991422e-03   4.93505970e-03
   3.69034940e-03   4.76422161e-03  -1.25827035e-03  -1.94680784e-03]
                                  ...

[ -3.92252317e-04  -3.66805331e-03   1.52376946e-03  -3.81564132e-05
  -2.57118000e-03  -4.46725264e-03   2.36480637e-03  -4.70252614e-03
  -4.18651942e-03   4.54758806e-03   4.38804098e-04   1.28351408e-03
   3.40470579e-03   1.00038981e-03  -1.06557179e-03   4.67202952e-03
   4.50591929e-03  -2.67829909e-03   2.57702312e-03  -3.65824508e-03
  -4.54068230e-03   2.20785337e-03  -1.00554363e-03   5.14690124e-04
   4.64830594e-03   1.91410910e-03  -4.83837258e-03   6.73376708e-05
  -2.37796479e-03  -4.45193471e-03  -2.60163331e-03   1.51159777e-03
   4.06868104e-03   2.55690538e-04  -2.54662265e-03   2.64597777e-03
  -2.62586889e-03  -2.71554058e-03   5.49281889e-04  -1.38776843e-03
  -2.94354092e-03  -1.13887887e-03   4.59292997e-03  -1.02300232e-03
   2.27600057e-03  -4.88117011e-03   1.95790920e-03   4.64376673e-04
   2.56658648e-03   8.90390365e-04  -1.40368659e-03  -6.40658545e-04
  -3.53228673e-03  -1.30717538e-03  -1.80223631e-03   2.94505036e-03
  -4.82233381e-03  -2.16079340e-03   2.58940039e-03   1.60595961e-03
  -1.22245611e-03  -6.72614493e-04   4.47060820e-03  -4.95934719e-03
   2.70283176e-03   2.93257344e-03   2.13279200e-04   2.59435410e-03
   2.98801321e-03  -2.79974379e-03  -1.49789048e-04  -2.53924704e-03
  -7.83207070e-04   1.18357304e-03  -1.27669750e-03  -4.16665291e-03
   1.40916929e-03   1.63017987e-07   1.36708119e-03  -1.26687710e-05
   1.24729215e-03  -2.50442210e-03  -3.20308795e-03  -1.41550787e-03
  -1.05747324e-03  -3.97984264e-03   2.25877413e-03  -1.28316227e-03
   3.60359484e-03  -1.97929185e-04   3.21712159e-03  -4.96298913e-03
  -1.83640339e-03  -9.90608009e-04  -2.03964626e-03  -4.87274351e-03
   7.24950165e-04   3.85614252e-03  -4.18979349e-03   2.73840013e-03]
```

Using tfidf, k-means would be implemented by the lines

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)
kmeans.fit(tfidf_matrix)
```

Using word2vec, k-means would be implemented by the lines

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)
kmeans.fit(word2vec_matrix)
```

(Here's an [example](http://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/k-means-clustering-example-word2vec/) of k-means with word2vec). So in the first case, k-means gets a matrix with the tf-idf values of each word per document, while in the second case k-means gets a vector for each word. How can k-means cluster the documents in the second case if it just has the word2vec representations?

Comment: Should this question be asked on stats.stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in clustering documents, probably the best you can do is to use the [Doc2Vec package](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), which can prepare a vector for each one of your documents. Then you can apply any clustering algorithm to the set of your document vectors for further processing. If, for any reason, you want to use word vectors instead, there are a few things you can do. Here is a very simple method:

1. For each document, collect all words with the highest TF-IDF values w.r.t. that document.
2. Average the Word2Vec vectors of those words to create a vector for the whole document
3. Apply your clustering on the averaged vectors.

Don't try to average *all* the words in a document, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So what you're saying is that the k-means algorithm assigns a vector to each document by averaging the vectors of the words it contains? (not including stopwords and stemming)

Comment: No, I'm saying you should prepare the document vectors yourself using the process I gave above, and then apply k-means on these documents vectors. Your goal is to cluster documents as far as I understand, isn't this the case?

Comment: I see I'm sorry! Yes that is the case indeed! Do you have any reference on using the tf-idf values as thresholds?

Comment: As about finding the optimal values for the threshold, you can experiment a bit. The more distinctive the words you use for each document (i.e. the highest the threshold), the better the results you will get. On the other hand, be sure that for each document you have at least two-three words to average (not sure how long are your documents).